# Android Studio 3.0 Canary 2 Still demands Jack for Java 8

Tags: java-8, android-studio-3.0

I tried to enable Java 8 in Android 3.0 Canary 2, but I get the error that Jack is needed for Java 8. But this annoucement https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html says that jack is no longer needed for 3.0 preview version. What am i doing wrong.

```
compileOptions {
  sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed the problem. I had tried to enable java 8 on an existing project created in Android 2.4. So the gradle version was 3.x . Uprading gradle to 4.x fixed the problem

Comment: It's interesting how I mostly read mentions of Androd Studio version, not gradle version. lul?